# rake test and test_structure.sql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rake, test-suite

First of all, I have to run "rake RAILS_ENV=test ..." to get the test suites to hit my test DB. Annoying but ok to live with.

However when I do so, I get a long stream of errors like so:

```
> rake RAILS_ENV=test -I test test:units
psql:/path/to/project/db/test_structure.sql:33: ERROR:  function "armor" already exists with same argument types
[and many more]
```

It looks like some DB definitions are getting unnecessarily reloaded. I can't find any mention of this on Google, so I was wondering whether others have seen this?

I am using a PostgreSQL database with the following in my environment.rb:

```
  config.active_record.schema_format = :sql
```

and using Rails 2.3.5 with rake 0.8.7.

**At this point I've fixed it but forgot how! I think I might have had pgcrypt loaded into the template schema, so the database was creating a "blank" database with it already loaded, and then rails was re-defining the functions from the saved schema. Unloading the functions from the template database would have fixed that.**

Answer (score 1):

The usual convention to run a rake task is as below:

```
> RAILS_ENV=test rake test:units
```

or as below:

```
> rake test:units RAILS_ENV=test
```

Can you try running in one of the above way? Hope that does the trick!

Comment: I do run it that way (the "-I test" was an unnecessary habit from running "ruby -I test ..." for a single test file).